Getting error with passthroughservice while upgrading from sitecore 9 to 10.2
I am working on a Sitecore upgrade project and we are encountering an issue after our solution upgrade.
Below is the attached screenshot.


        Server Error in '/' Application.
    ________________________________________
    Implementation type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.PassthroughService' can't be converted to service type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.IPassthroughService'
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred.
    
    Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Implementation type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.PassthroughService' can't be converted to service type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.IPassthroughService'
    
    Source Error:
    
    Line 13:             foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
    Line 14:             {
    Line 15:                 @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.Item, Model.RenderingWebEditingParams, Model)
    Line 16:             }
    Line 17:         }
    
    Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc102sc.dev.local\Views\Variants\Page Content.cshtml    Line: 15
    
    Stack Trace:
    
    [ArgumentException: Implementation type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.PassthroughService' can't be converted to service type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.IPassthroughService']
       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite..ctor(ResultCache cache, Type serviceType, ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, ServiceCallSite[] parameterCallSites) +246
       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +455
       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot) +377
       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +84
       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +152
       System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +75
       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType) +97
       System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +75
       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) +46
       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) +132
       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters) +485
       Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +481
    
    [ConfigurationException: Could not create object from service provider . Config XML: <processor type="VGWMP.Foundation.HCPSiteExtensions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSortedReference, VGWMP.Foundation.HCPSiteExtensions" resolve="true" patch:source="VGWMP.Foundation.HCPSiteExtensions.VariantField.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />]
       Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +641
       Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +138
       Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +68
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode) +91
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode) +138
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters) +136
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1255
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +420
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +114
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +420
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +114
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderReference.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +631
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +132
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +420
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +132
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +420
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +132
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +420
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +132
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +420
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +132
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +420
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +132
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +420
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +132
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +420
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +114
       (Object , Object ) +9
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Renderers.VariantRenderer.RenderVariantField(BaseVariantField variant, Item item, Dictionary`2 parameters) +240
       Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Extensions.RenderingVariantsExtensions.RenderVariant(BaseVariantField variantField, Item item, RenderingWebEditingParams parameters, Object model, Func`3 hrefOverrideFunc) +207
       ASP._Page_Views_Variants_Page_Content_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc102sc.dev.local\Views\Variants\Page Content.cshtml:15
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
       System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +91
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +698



The interface Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.IPassthroughService interface has been marked as obsolete in Sitecore 10.2.
Alternative: Use the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Services.IPassthroughService interface instead.
Please try this alternative and let me know if you encounter any further issues.

The error you are getting in the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.PassthroughService. If you try to extract the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions DLL you will get the information about it.
using System;

#nullable disable
namespace Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services
{
  [Obsolete("This interface is obsolete since SXA 10.2. It will be removed after two consecutive releases. Use Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Services.IPassthroughService instead")]
  public interface IPassthroughService : Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Services.IPassthroughService
  {
  }
}

To resolve this you need to use the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Services.IPassthroughService
Here is the reference screenshot.

Hope this helps.

The interface Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.IPassthroughService has become obsolete in Sitecore 10.2.

You will need to resolve the dependency for IPassthroughService inside the render variant field extension VGWMP.Foundation.HCPSiteExtensions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSortedReference, VGWMP.Foundation.HCPSiteExtensions with the following interface in order to resolve this issue.
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Services.IPassthroughService

The reason you are getting this issue is because Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.IPassthroughService is no longer resolved through dependency injection in Sitecore 10.2.
As an additional note you can check the dependency injection resolution for an interface on the following url /sitecore/admin/ShowServicesConfig.aspx, to know the interface and class that is being resolved through dependency injection.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
